# Is there a simpler way to create a sum of previous values in an array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm basically looking for a simpler way to do this:

```
heights.forEach((height, i) => {
    var p = i > 0 ? i -1  : 0;
    this.breakingPoints.push(height+heights[p])
})
```

If I input an array that is:

```
[0,2,5,5]
```

I would like to output

```
[0,2,7,12]
```

Comment: That looks pretty simple and straightforward to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `map()` method with closure to return new array.

```js
const arr = [0,2,5,5];
const result = (s => arr.map(e => s += e))(0);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Took me a while to understand why the s => ...(0) was there, but I guess it's just to declare s as temp variable.

Comment: I like this simple one-liner solution. But for anyone who don't understand the `(s => ....)(0)` part, basically it's the same as using `var s = 0` as temporary variable and then using it inside `.map()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store the variable to push in a variable which will allow you to automatically sum the new value to it without checking the index.

```
var total = 0;
heights.forEach(height => {
    this.breakingPoints.push(total += height);
})
```

The result would be:

```
[0, 2, 7, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```
let inputArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let outputArray = [];
inputArray.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex) { 
  return outputArray[currentIndex] = accumulator + currentValue; }, 0);
```

Comment: I thought reduce output a single value?

Comment: Yes it does, but look into the callback method. There it is updating the output array on every index.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reduce and spread operator to concat values:

```
const input = [0, 2, 5, 5];
const output = input.reduce((acc, val) => [...acc, (acc[acc.length - 1] ? acc[acc.length - 1] : 0) + val],[]);
```

Or when using < ES6

```
var output = input.reduce(function (acc, val) { return acc.concat([(acc[acc.length - 1] ? acc[acc.length - 1] : 0) + val]); }, []);
```